# QR scanner in Swift 5

Tags: swift, avfoundation, qr-code

I built a QR scanner in Swift 5. It will acknowledge the QR Code and scan it, however it only pulls up the url that is embedded in the QR code. Does anyone have any advice on how to make it so that I can tap the link and open it in a browser?

This is the code I have for the scanner:

```swift
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

extension QRScannerController: AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    
}

class QRScannerController: UIViewController {
    
    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var qrcodeFrameView: UIView?
    
    
    @IBOutlet var messageLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var topBar: UIView!
    
    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        // Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it cotains at least one object
        if metadataObjects.count == 0 {
            qrcodeFrameView?.frame = CGRect.zero
            messageLabel.text = "No QR Code is detected"
            return
        }
        
        //Get the metadata object
        let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
        
        if metadataObj.type == AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr {
            // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text and set the bounds
        let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj)
        qrcodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds
        
        if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
            messageLabel.text = metadataObj.stringValue
            }
        
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // get back camera for capture
        guard let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back) else {
            print("Failed to get camera device")
            return
        }
        
        do {
            // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDeviceInput class using the previous device object
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
            
            //Set the input device on the capture session
            captureSession.addInput(input)
            
            //Initialize a AVCaptureMetadataOutput object and set it as the output device to the capture session
            let captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
            captureSession.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)
            
            //Set delegate and use the default dispatch queue to execute the call back
            captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr]
            
            // Initialize the video preview layer and add it as a sublayer to the viewPreview view's layer
            videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
            videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
            videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
            view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)
            
            //Start video capture
            captureSession.startRunning()
            
            // Move the message label and top bar to the front
            view.bringSubviewToFront(messageLabel)
            view.bringSubviewToFront(topBar)
            
            // Initialize QR Code Frame to highlight the QR Code
            qrcodeFrameView = UIView()
            
            if let qrcodeFrameView = qrcodeFrameView {
                qrcodeFrameView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
                qrcodeFrameView.layer.borderWidth = 2
                view.addSubview(qrcodeFrameView)
                view.bringSubviewToFront(qrcodeFrameView)
            }
            
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: UIApplication.shared.openURL(urlStr)

Comment: Thanks man. Just curious where would I add it in the code?